# $\mu$ is a Radon measure$\implies \lambda(E):=\int_E f\,d\mu$ is also a Radon measure?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,B,\mu)$ be a measure space (with $B$ the Borel sigma-algebra) and let Let $f\in L^1(X,\mu)$. I was wondering if

> $\mu$ is a Radon measure$\implies \lambda(E):=\int_E f\,d\mu$ is also a
> Radon measure

(Should I add more conditions on $f$? Is $f\in L^1$ necessary?).

For instance I would like to prove inner regularity on open sets.
Since $\mu$ is Radon so inner regular on open sets we have, $\mu(O)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset O\text{ is compact}\}$ so if I fix $\varepsilon>0$ (that can be arbitrary small), there is $K\subset O$ which is compact and such that $\mu(K)\ge \mu(O)-\varepsilon$. So $$\int_O f\,d\mu=\int_K f\,d\mu + \underbrace{\int_{O\setminus K} f \, d\mu}_{\le|f|_{L^1}\cdot\varepsilon}.$$ I think I can use the same reasonning to show that $\lambda$ is outer regular.

Also, for $K$ compact I have $\lambda(K)=\int_K f\,d\mu \le |f|_{L^1}\mu(K)<\infty$ since $f$ is integrable (so $|f|_{L^1}<\infty)$ and $\mu$ is a radon measure (so $\mu(K)<\infty$). Is this reasoning correct or is  there a quicker way to notice that $\lambda$ is Radon?

Comment: There are no open or compact sets in a general measure sapce.

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725401/mu-and-nu-be-borel-measures-on-mathcalbx-mu-nu-then-mu-is?rq=1

Comment: The claimed bound $\int_K f\,d\mu \le \|f\|_{L^1} \cdot \mu(K)$ is not true in general.  For instance, consider $\mu(K) < 1$ and $f = 1_K$.

Comment: @NateEldredge but is there another argument or the result doesn't hold?

Comment: I changed each occurrence of $\text{“}f d\mu\text{”}$ in this question to $\text{“}f\,d\mu\text{”}. \qquad $

Comment: An alternative to $f \in L^1$ is to have $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ and $f \ge 0$.  The proof needs some tweaks then (e.g. monotone convergence instead of dominated convergence).  But you need some kind of integrability to have the definition of $\lambda$ even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try working with sequences.  Find an increasing sequence of compact sets $K_1 \subset K_2 \subset \dots \subset O$ such that $\mu(O \setminus K_n) \to 0$.  Verify that $1_{O \setminus K_n} \to 0$, $\mu$-almost everywhere.    Now use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $\lambda(O \setminus K_n) = \int_{O \setminus K_n} f\,d\mu \to 0$ as well.